Clickable function is not working for some devices in glance android
there is strange issue with glance, this function is working on Huawei devices perfectly but some reason in Pixel and some other devices even clickable function is not triggered why it happens and what is the solution? I don't prefer to use lambda function, if possible I just want to make it work with other devices without changing implementation.
GlanceModifier.size(screenSize.dp).clickable(
                actionStartActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(errorDeepLink)).apply {
                    flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                })
            )

